# What is C++ equivalent of Java StdIn.isEmpty()

Tags: java, c++, file-io, input

I am trying to learn something basing on Java resource, and I want to adapt it to C++.

Source of Java has:

```
while( !StdIn.isEmpty())
{
  //Take input from standard input, and process it...
}
```

In C++ the closest solution I could come up with was

```
while( cin >> someString)
{
  //process someString...
}
```

However, the problem is, that cin returns state of object. There is no way I can put wrong input into std::string. This could have worked for ints, but not for string. Any equivalent function, or workarounds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure you can. Try entering EOF.

Comment: It's not clear, at least to me, what you're trying to do.

Comment: There is no `StdIn` class in the standard Java API. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry if I cause some chaos, as I'm not familiar with Java. From what I can read from code in Java, the program is looping until standard input is empty. While it isn't, program gets string from standard input, and processes this string. 

I found StdIN:
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdIn.java.html
The program also uses StdOut.print(someString) to print string to standard output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++ iostreams, and also with C's stdio, you cannot tell whether a file (such as `std::cin`/`stdin`) *will be empty if you were to try reading from it*. The only way to find out is to *actually* read from the file, and *then* check whether the attempt succeeded.

(Yes, you could use some form of `peek`, but that's nowhere near as idiomatic or practical.)

So a standard method in C++ might look like this, processing entire lines of input at a time:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
{
    // process "line"
}
```

The loop body will only execute *if* you succeeded at extracting one line from the input. Once the input runs out of data, the loop condition is no longer satisfied (i.e. the stream is no longer "good"), and the loop stops.

The same idea applies to C's `fgets`, as well as to unformatted `std::istream::read()` and `fread`, and to platform-specific functions like Posix's `read(2)`: You always *attempt* to obtain input, then *check* whether you got any input, and only if you did do you proceed to consume the input.

Comment: Hey Kerrek, thanks for reply. Are you sure your code will work? For me(GCC 4.8.1) it always works. If I press enter, it still continues(string is empty, looks like it is valid). Or maybe I take concept of all this wrong?

Comment: @MatthewRock: Big misunderstanding of what "standard input" is: Enter just creates a new line, it doesn't close the standard input. The reader just blocks, waiting for more. To close the standard input you have to do something else, like press Ctrl-D, or don't read from the console, but rather a redirection: `echo "abc" | ./a.out`

Comment: Great. Thanks for answer then. I was afraid this was an option.

Comment: @MatthewRock: If you want to read until the user enters an empty line, then change the loop to `for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line) && !line.empty(); )` -- Or just test for an empty string inside the loop, and handle as appropriate.